# How to wakeup ubuntu (16.04) from suspended state?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, wakeup

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on power mac laptop. If I close the laptop, it won't automatically fall asleep and will run out of charge within about 8 hours.
I tried to use the command

```
systemctl suspend
```

The command works, and puts the system into sleep. But when I try to wake it up, it does not wake up, and I have to do a hard restart with the power button.

Is there any trick to it, that I am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an old kernel because that may be the problem causing it to be unable to wake up. You can do this with

```
uname -a
```

and to download the new kernel follow this guide

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/install-linux-kernel-4-7-ubuntu-16-04/

Otherwise, you can always try to install a previous LTS.